# Adding label on a D3 bar chart

Tags: svg, charts, d3.js, label

I read a lot of documentation about adding label on a D3 bar chart but i can't figure it out. I am stuck with what to add after the "svg.selectAll("text")".

The result would just be the same as in this example :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
      if ((d / 1000000) >= 1) {
        d = d / 1000000  + " " + "000" + " " + "000";
      }
      return d;
    });
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("./test.csv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.internaute = +d.internaute;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.internaute; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
     .append("text")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", 30)
      .attr("dx", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Date");


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Internautes");


  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.internaute); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.internaute);});

    svg.selectAll("text")
     //???? //

});
```

Thank you in advance. I hope to get the hold of it :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work !

```
var yTextPadding = 20;
svg.selectAll(".bartext")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class", "bartext")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("x", function(d,i) {
    return x(i)+x.rangeBand()/2;
})
.attr("y", function(d,i) {
    return height-y(d)+yTextPadding;
})
.text(function(d){
     return d;
});
```

Notice how I use a class (.bartext) to identify the chart labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I had to change a few things but you gave me the logic in order to make it work. Here is my code on Jsfiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dzzNc/).

I don't know if it's the best way but it was worth trying. The hardest part was to know what to "add" especially when you have "d" and "i" but the main part to consider seems to be the last return statement.

Comment: Ha, Frenchman too ! The reason I added a class .bartext is because it is then easier to access the style attributes you want to change in your CSS. In your code for example you could very well put text-anchor: middle and fill: white in your CSS, thus separating your style definitions (which is more view-oriented) from your javascript (more data oriented, unless of course you want your style to be a function of the data, which is mainly not the case here). Saved me from a lot of headaches !