# Adding text labels in middle of each bar - stacked bar chart & Mouse Over Events

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I created a Stacked Bar Chart using the demo in this [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208).

I'd like add text in the middle of each bar.

And also on hovering the chart I'd like get a arrow with some text like that.

I don't have any clue on how to do it.

Any suggestions will be very much helpful.

**JS :**

```
var width = 550,
      height = 500;

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["#D70B16", "#154CEF", "#1A8A55"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

  var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 + "," + 30 + ")");

  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "state"; }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var y0 = 0;
      d.value = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
      d.total = d.value[d.value.length - 1].y1;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.state;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.total;})])

    svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

    svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Values");

    var state = svgContainer.selectAll(".state")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.state) + ",0)"; });

    state.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d.value; })
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


    state.append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d3.format(".2s")(d.y1); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1)+16; })
        .style("stroke", '#000');

  })
```

**DATA :**

```
state,value1, value2, value3
state1, 80, 10, 20
state2, 90, 5, 10
state3, 70, 15, 35
state4, 90, 3, 27
state5, 50, 25, 55
state6, 85, 8, 27
```

Comment: http://www.verisi.com/resources/d3-tutorial-basic-charts.htm#s6

Comment: You can figure out the position for the text using the dimensions of each `rect` element you're appending. Then you can append `text` elements at those positions. For hover, you can use the `.on("mouseover", function() {})` handler.

Comment: Lars - On hover I wanted to make all bars disappear except the selected one. Can you let me know how to do it?

Comment: Something like `.on("click", function(d) { state.selectAll("rect").filter(function(e) { return e == d; }).remove(); })`.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't help me out.

Comment: Could you post a complete working example please?

Answer (score 3):

This question deals with adding labels to a non-stacked bar chart: [Adding label on a D3 bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057917/adding-label-on-a-d3-bar-chart)

It appears to be very applicable here.