# d3 - trigger event on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I've somehow managed to do create a stacked bar chart for this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345572/d3-adding-text-labels-in-middle-of-each-bar-stacked-bar-chart-mouse-over-e).

Instead of hover method i've chosen to get on with click event as i was facing some bug with the hover event like the elements were not disappearing properly when i hover on to a element.

When i click on a bar all the bars are getting disappeared and the width of the bar is getting increased. But that when I click on the bar that's been expanded i want to reset it's width to the original width.

1. I wanted to know how to get back to it's original width[when i was using hover method i defined the width manually]
2. Need to how to code for the send click event for the expanded bar.

Please help.

**JS :**

```
var width = 750,
      height = 500;

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["#D70B16", "#154CEF", "#1A8A55"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

  var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 + "," + 30 + ")");


  function movein() {
    var allRect = d3.selectAll("rect")
                    // .transition()
                    // .duration(300)
                    .attr("opacity", 0)
                    .attr("display", "none")

    d3.select(this)
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .attr("display", "block")

    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .delay(300)
      .duration(500)
      .attr("width", 300)
  };

  function moveout() {  
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("width", 150)

      var allRect = d3.selectAll("rect")
                    .transition()
                    .delay(1000)
                    .duration(300)
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .attr("display", "block")
  };

  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "circle"; }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var y0 = 0;
      d.hours = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
      d.total = d.hours[d.hours.length - 1].y1;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.circle;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.total;})])

    svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

    svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Login Hours");

    var circle = svgContainer.selectAll(".circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.circle) + ",0)"; });

    circle.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d.hours; })
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
          .on("click", movein)
          .on("click", moveout)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  })
```

**DATA :**

```
state,value1, value2, value3
state1, 80, 10, 20
state2, 90, 5, 10
state3, 70, 15, 35
state4, 90, 3, 27
state5, 50, 25, 55
state6, 85, 8, 27
```

Comment: It sounds like you would need to check the width of the bar in the `click` handler and, if it's so wide as to cover the entire graph, shrink.

Comment: Lars - I'm here trying to expand the bar that's been clicked and disappear all the other bars. And once again when clicked on the bar that's been expanded. I wanted to shrink that bar to the original size and make the invisible bars to appear. Please help.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please (e.g. in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))? The code you've posted doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you resolve this? You could create an attr for each bar. When clicked, append it's value by one. In the same click event, if the attr > 1 then fire the click twice event, and reset the click attr.