# Add text on top of bar in d3js chart -- no <text> elements added

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am creating a bar chart with d3.js from data stored in tsv file. I want to insert a text in each bar. How I can do?
I have tried even this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057917/adding-label-on-a-d3-bar-chart), but doesn't work.

Here is the code of my function:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


function visualize(file){
    d3.tsv(file, function(error, data) {

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.weight = +d.weight;
      });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.concept; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.weight; })]);


      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("weight");

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect").style("fill", function (d){return d.color;})
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.concept); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.weight); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.weight); });

       svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(function(d) {
            return d.concept;
       })
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("x", x)
       .attr("y",y)
       .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
       .attr("font-size", "11px")
       .attr("fill", "white");

    });

}
```

All my code with the files tsv are here: [full code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp76jwvi0p1fni2/bar.zip)

Comment: P.S.  I changed the title.  When I first read "insert text inside bar", I expected the problem to be that you were actually trying to add the text as a child of the rectangle (like adding a span inside a div in HTML), which is another source of confusion for d3/svg beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmeliaBR is right as usual, and I am only putting this answer because while I was working on it, I saw myself changing the code so that it really makes use of the Enter, Update, Exit selection paradigm. I have made quite a few changes in that regard. Here is the code, FWIW:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("weight");

var g = svg.append("g");

function update(file){
d3.tsv(file, function(error, data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.weight = +d.weight;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.concept; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.weight; })]);

var bar = g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data);

bar.enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar");

bar
    .style("fill", function (d){return d.color;})
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.concept); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.weight); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.weight); });

bar.exit().remove();

var text = g.selectAll(".text")
    .data(data);

text.enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("class","text");

text
    .attr("text-anchor", "right")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.concept); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.weight) + 22;})
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .text(function(d) {
    return d.concept;
});

text.exit().remove();
});
}
```

And you call it like by doing `update("data16.tsv")` and then `update("data15.tsv")`.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw an axis, it creates separate `<text>` elements for each label inside the axis group inside the SVG.  So if you then try to select all the `<text>` elements in the SVG, you're going to select all your axis labels.  If you have more axis labels than data for text elements, your `enter()` selection will be empty and nothing will happen.

To be sure you're only selecting the correct `<text>` elements, give your text labels a class to distinguish them from the axis labels.  And then use that class to narrow-down your selector:

```
svg.selectAll("text.bar-label")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("class", "bar-label")
```

Comment: Sorry. I want this behavior http://alignedleft.com/content/03-tutorials/01-d3/130-making-a-bar-chart/18.png. With your code you modify the axes label