# d3 use drop down to filter for column headers

Tags: d3.js

I have data in a csv with countries as columns headers and a timeseries of row data with date as the primary key.

What I am attempting should be fairly straight forward but I haven't been able to get it to work. 
I have a drop down box which contains the country column headers. Once on of these is selected I want to reference the selection to fill a chart.

I currently have this working if I explicitly state the name of the column header i.e if the header is USA which will load all data for that column.

```
data1.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
                    d.country= d.USA;

                    });
```

But I need this to be based on the item selected which I can get by

```
var myCountry = this.options[this.selectedIndex].__data__;
```

I am just missing how to use this variable to reference the column d.USA

Comment: A working example of your issue, like a jsfiddle, would be nice here.  Have you tried `d.country = d[myCountry]; `

Comment: here is an example of this http://jsfiddle.net/enzo267/4h9S2/7/ line 81 reference d.USA but I would like this to be based on the drop down selection at line 74

Comment: There are several problems with this implementation...data clobbering and not following the Enter/Update/Exit pattern makes this not suited to updates. The only way to make this work with *minimal changes* is to safeguard the data from the alterations to it and remove chart elements between renditions, like you can see [in this fiddle that I hacked](http://jsfiddle.net/LLqbX/1/). But, again, this is no way to live and someone else with more time available can build something better than this.

Comment: In general the column headers wouldn't be known and the drop down would be populated automatically, hence this wouldn't really be an option unless I list out every possible case which I would like to avoid. I am sure this can be done and if you could point me a general direction this would be appreciated. I am new to d3, and have seen something similar achieved using the map function but I am not sure how this would work in this case

Comment: The most solid foundation in D3 is understanding the Enter/Update/Exit pattern (I keep calling it EUE). It is fundamental to grasp this for elegantly representing data updates (quantitatively or qualitatively). [Here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) is the canonical writing on this. In a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734419/add-text-on-top-of-bar-in-d3js-chart-no-text-elements-added/21736232#21736232), I re-worked the original code in the question to make use of the pattern. I am constantly writing exercise pieces to engrave this in my mind :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was a simple fix which I tried previously and Josh suggested but did not work in my original code. jsfiddle.net/enzo267/hK8kG/1