# How to select data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

I have below code to display  chart

```
        d3.json("dat.csv", function(error, data) {


        Data.forEach(function(d) {

            d.Data = parseDate(d.Data);
            d.Free = +d.Free;

        });
```

This is picking data form all hosts , I want to restrict it to pick data.  field will have all host names. how to put a check  the data? please help

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: `data = data.filter()`

Comment: Yes. You can easily check this.

Comment: Add a sample object `d` from data array to your question. Is `d.host.name` has host name of current object or 'all host names'  as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Change 'host1Data' to 'data' since you're still using 'data' in the rest of your code. I used 'host1Data' for clarity in my answer. You should either not use it as a new variable name, or use it and change all subsequent references to 'data' to 'host1Data'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your data after receiving the d3.json response. I created a new variable (host1Data) for clarity:

```
d3.json("dat.json", function(error, data) {

    var host1Data = data.filter(function(d){
                        return d.host.name === 'host1';
                    });

    host1Data.forEach(function(d) {

        d.Date.Time = parseDate(d.Date.Time);
        d.CPU.Free = +d.CPU.Free;

    });

    // Use host1Data instead of data in the rest of your code
});
```

Alternatively, you can also filter the data when passing it to svg using javascript's filter function:

```
var mychart = svg.selectAll(".mychart")
  .data(data.filter(function(d){return d.host.name === 'host1'})
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "mychart");
```

Or using d3's filter function:

```
var mychart = svg.selectAll(".mychart")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("g")
  .filter(function(d){return d.host.name === 'host1'}
  .attr("class", "mychart");
```

Comment: You might want to post a fiddle if you're still having issues. I can't possibly debug your problem from the 4 lines of code in you question.

Comment: You can filter and view as many as you want in one html file (within reason). However, since your javascript is in the html file, i don't think you can use that filtered data in a different html file. The only way i think you could do that is by using something like Angular, Backbone or Ember where different views (html files) can share the same models/controllers (script). In any case, for a simple use case like yours why not just have multiple files with the same code but filtering for diff hosts?

Comment: I thought you wanted to view them simultaneously. Take a look at this question which also contains a fiddle doing something like what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861587/d3-use-drop-down-to-filter-for-column-headers

Comment: Can you please see the above code and let me know what should be modified to implement the logic of drop down list value selected by user. I had refered this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/spanndemic/5JRMt/)

Comment: @joy This is a really bad idea: your edit incorporated the solution to your original question and thereby completely distorted its meaning. If you have another question or a follow-up, please post a new question instead. I have rolled back your last edit to preserve the original meaning of the question and this answer.