# Adding Label Text on Barchart D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to displays labels that will sit on top of each bar in my bar chart. I'd also like them to display a % after the number.

Here is my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/FbIquWxfLjcRTg7tiX4E?p=preview

I experimented with using this code from the question found in the link below. However, I wasnt able to get it to work properly (meaning the whole chart failed to display)

[Adding label on a D3 bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057917/adding-label-on-a-d3-bar-chart)

```
var yTextPadding = 20;
svg.selectAll(".bartext")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class", "bartext")
.attr("text-anchor", "top")
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("x", function(d,i) {
    return x(i)+x.rangeBand()/2;
})
.attr("y", function(d,i) {
    return height-y(d)+yTextPadding;
})
.text(function(d){
     return d;
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the most straight forward way given your existing code:

```
    // keep a reference to the g holding the rects
    var rectG = g.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
        .enter();

    // append the rects the same way as before
    rectG.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

    // now add the text to the g
    rectG.append("text")
      .text(function(d){
        return d.value + '%';
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key) + (x1.bandwidth()/2); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wkD4z0Sn2zC7N71mLmVN?p=preview).

Comment: This is great! This will end up being really helpful to apply to other charts of mine in the same style. Good to know I was going about it the wrong way!